# Text selection by href value

Tags: jsoup

I have a little doubt in html parsing using Jsoup and Java.

Consider this html section

```
<a href="/path/page1.html">Page1</a>
<a href="/joe/jeo.html">joe</a>
<a href="/path/page2.html">Page2</a>
<a href="/harry/harry.html">harry</a>
<a href="/mike/mike.html">mike</a>
<a href="/path/page3.html">Page3</a>
```

I need to extract with Jsoup just Page1, Page2 and Page3.
The only thing that pages have in common is "path" into the href value.
Anyone knows how to select text through a sort of "contain" in href value?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post what you've tried already?

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex on the selector:

```
doc.select("a[href~=(?i)(path)]");
```

Try this:

```
Document doc;
         String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0";
        try {

            // need http protocol
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://domain.tld/page.html").userAgent(userAgent).get();


            Elements links = doc.select("a[href~=(?i)(path)]");
            for (Element link: links ) {


                System.out.println("\nLink with path: " + link.toString());

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```